# The daisy function from the cluster package returns error on data

Tags: r, r-daisy, factoextra

I want to use ordinal data (1,2,3,4) of 59 observables with 322 variables and daisy, eventually leading to a cluster analysis. I use the script below on an excel input file (csv). After daisy, the following error message occurs:

```
> Error in daisy(grb, stand = TRUE) :    ungültiger Typ character für
> Spaltennummern 1 In addition: Warning messages: 1: In data.matrix(x) :
> NAs introduced by coercion 2: In daisy(grb, stand = TRUE) :  
> Binärvariable 2, 3, 4,
```

The grb data contain the row names in the first column, and the column titles in the first line. daisy seems to think it has to use the first column: How can I tell it  no to do that? The input data look ok.

Secondly, daisy thinks the data a binaries, but they are oridnals, 1-4. How to correct this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Script:

```
library(readr)
grb <- read_delim("~/R/Projects/Datasets/Ges.csv", 
                  ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
attach(grb)
library(cluster)
data(grb)
head(grb, 2)
d.d <- daisy(grb, stand = TRUE)
grb.hc <- hclust(d.d, method = "ward.D2")
library("factoextra")
fviz_dend(grb.hc, cex=.5, horiz = TRUE)
```

Comment: Show the errors/warnings in english please

Comment: Error in daisy(grb, stand = TRUE) :    non valid type character for
> column 1 In addition: Warning messages: 1: In data.matrix(x) :
> NAs introduced by coercion 2: In daisy(grb, stand = TRUE) :  
> binary variable 2, 3, 4,